# Trying to extract frames to memory using fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract frames directly to memory with FFmpeg to save time writing the frames on disk since I don't need it

I tried running with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050534/how-to-read-video-frames-directly-into-memory-with-nodejs) code in the first place but it didn't work

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
const RVF = (path,HW)=>{
     //HW is hxw string of each frame 

    const command = ffmpeg(path,{stdoutLines:0}).size(HW)
    .addOutputOption(['-f image2'])
    .on('error',(err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })

    const ffstream = command.pipe()
    let numOfFrames = 0

    ffstream.on('data',(chunck)=>{
          // to check if the data is right frame of no 
          // first frame passes this correctly
        console.log(tf.node.decodeImage(chunck).shape)
        console.log(chunck.length)
        console.log(`frames ${++numOfFrames}`)
    })
}
```

first frames is extracted correctly but I am getting this error on the second one

```
Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=3.9 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=N/A speed=1.71x
video:101kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: this is no longer a tensorflow.js issue. It is related to how you stream your video using the library

Comment: I don't have experience with FFmpeg just trying to read frames to mem

Comment: the problem is with -f flag i think when i use image2 it works correctly with tf.node.decode but when i use raw video it extracts everything but not correctly like my video is 251 frame and '-f rawvideo' makes it about 3000

Comment: It is possible to specify with ffmpeg how many frame to generate with the -v flag. The only thing is to specify at which time frequency to take the frame

Comment: can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: I am not an expert using this library, but I provided a working snippet with the previous code that uses directly `ffmpeg`